# How connect to my geth from Remix? IPC is always \\\.\\pipe\\geth.ipc

Tags: go-ethereum, remix, ipc, rpc

I am trying to develop smart contract & dapp with Window 10.

I made my own accounts in local testnet in geth.

And I'd like to make smart contracts and deploy them on the Remix.

so I need to approach to my geth from Remix.

I switch environment option from Javascript Vm/Injected Wev3 to Web3 provider!

then it required "Web3 Provider Endpoint".

Default was http://localhost:8545. (it doesn't work)

I heard that 8545 is RPC port, and localhost is IPC.

when I run my geth, I can check my RPC port.

<< HTTP endpoint opened url = hrrp://0.0.0.0:9797 >>

However, I can't know my geth IP

it is always indicated like below

<< IPC endpoint opened url= \.\pipe\geth.ipc

I can't refer my IP

How can I control my geth on Remix?

---

Comment: Not possible to connect to the Web3 provider. Make sure the provider is running and a connection is open (via IPC or RPC).

Comment: I am already using http Remix not https.

Comment: What is your geth launch command?

Comment: I did 3 commands like belows

Comment: geth --networkid 7979 --nodiscover --port "30303" --datadir \Users\Doo\Desktop\data_testnet --rpc --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpcport 9797 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,personal,web3" --nat "any" console

Comment: geth --dev --networkid 2525 --nodiscover --port 3030 --datadir \Users\Doo\Desktop\data_testnet --rpc --rpcaddr 125.191.63.110 --rpcport "8552" --rpcapi "admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,,txpool,personal,web3" console

Comment: geth --networkid 7979 --nodiscover --maxpeers 0 --datadir \Users\Doo\Desktop\data_testnet --mine --minerthreads 1 --rpc --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpcport 9797 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,personal,web3" --unlock 0,1 --password \Users\Doo\Desktop\data_testnet\passwd --verbosity 6 console

Comment: and also did this  ------------>       geth --networkid 7979 --nodiscover --maxpeers 0 --datadir \Users\Doo\Desktop\data_testnet --mine --minerthreads 1 --rpc --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpcport 9797 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,personal,web3" --unlock=0x92887bd80de61d79e390500a99fb1f786851f7b3 --password pass0 --verbosity 6 console

Comment: Your launch command seems correct, it should connect to http://localhost:9797 assuming all run in the same machine. Do you have a firewall installed?

Comment: do I have to install it?? I didnt install firewall individually. i just installed windows10 and have been developing

Comment: localhost:9797     it worked! thank you so much Ismael!! :)

Comment: @madooyu Can you help with this question , I am trying the same in ubuntu 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55417453/error-while-connecting-from-remix-via-rpc-to-local-blockchain

Comment: @Ismael I am using the below command ,
geth --datadir ./accnt1/ --networkid 2018 --port 30306 --nodiscover --rpc  --rpccorsdomain=”*” --rpcapi “db,personal,eth,net,web3,debug” --rpcaddr='0.0.0.0' --rpcport 8545 console

It gets started  , but I am not able to connect from Remix , This is the question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55417453/error-while-connecting-from-remix-via-rpc-to-local-blockchain